# SQL Database data reduction

Tags: c#, sql, database, boolean, store

I have created an SQL database in Visual Studio using C#. The database is a records store, so it stores customers, records and Purchase.
All seem to work fine, but when a customer makes a purchase, the records in the record table should be accessed, and then, if i was to call that record again, it should allow me.
But I just struggle to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: to be honest i have no idea how to do

Comment: Show us what code you've tried, which data access library you're using, and what error you get. This is too vague for anyone to answer.

Comment: Indeed show us your code and explain what's wrong in detail. We can only guess so far. My guess is that you're making a new database each time you run the app and lose your past data, but without code I can't help.